# How can I run ignored tests with TeamCity's NUnit runner?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, teamcity

I want to run all the ignored tests in my solution in a different build configuration in TeamCity.
I didn't see any explicit why to do it in the build step configuration page.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 7):

The Ignore attribute is the wrong thing to use here. It should be used for tests you do not wish to run at all. Try using [Categories](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=category&r=2.2.10) instead. TeamCity has two properties you can set within an NUnit build step.

[NUnit categories include and NUnit categories exclude](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD7/NUnit) control which tests will be run.

Comment: We do this to partition a large set of tests into about 15 parallel builds, using a separate category for each build.  It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

How did you mark your tests - your question is not quite clear in this point? Did you use the `Explicit` or `Ignored` attribute? If the latter then these tests will not run at all.